# twig:concatenate two strings in a trinary inside HTML attribute

Tags: twig, concatenation

```
<a class="menu-item" href="{{(haveSubMenu == 'yes')?'#':(item.url|e ~ (item.hash ? item.hash|e : ''))}}"></a>
```

What I wanna do is simple, if the menu-item has submenu, then its href should be `#`, if not, then get its URL. But the above code doesn't work, because when `~` convert its operands to string, it converts all `&`s in `item.url` to `&amp;`, which breaks the link.

So what is the correct way to write this?

Comment: You missing a double `=` in the first if on `haveSubMenu`

Comment: A glitch, thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling autoscape to all the code with the [autoescape tag](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/autoescape.html).

So with this code:

```
{% autoescape false %}
    Everything will be outputted as is in this block
<a class="menu-item" href="{{(haveSubMenu == 'yes')?'#':(item.url|e ~ (item.hash ? item.hash : ''))}}"></a>
{% endautoescape %}
```

See the working (and running code with example) in [this twigfiddle URL](http://twigfiddle.com/8sqw10).

If this don't work as you expected feel free to specific some testing data.

Hope this help